# Basis of the space of polynomial functions with degree at most n over a finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-fields

What is the dimension of the space of all polynomial functions of degree at most $n$ over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_2$?

I know that for over the field $\mathbb{R}$, the dimension is $n+1$, since we have the basis $1, x, x^2, \dots, x^n$. But I'm wondering how this would change if the field is $\mathbb{F}_2$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: As polynomials, same for any field. As functions, $x^n$ is the same as $x$ for all $n\ge1$, so dimension is two.

Comment: Understood, toolman?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has lost interest.